# How to use Apache Pulsar with Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, apache-pulsar, spring-pulsar

There is no official library of Apache Pulsar for Spring Cloud Stream.
I found [Spring for Apache Pulsar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_dependencies), but it is only about Spring Boot.
In it's GitHub repository, there is a [spring-pulsar-spring-cloud-stream-binder], but not found in mvnrepository. So how can I use it?

Is there a good way of integrating Apache Pulsar in Spring Cloud Stream?

Answer (score 5):

The Spring Cloud Stream binder of the Spring for Apache Pulsar project has not been part of a release yet. It will most likely be part of the next release.
If you can't wait, maybe you can build it from the main git branch ?

Comment: Hi, i see the project is based on Gradle which i'm not familiar with. Currently we use are using mvn. And maybe it's not a good idea to maintain a copy ourselves. So do you have a plan like when it is going to released approximately?

Comment: It is the official SCS library. It is not yet on Maven Central but you can use snapshot releases as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#appendix.non-ga-versions).

Comment: Until the ref docs are updated w/ the SCS info, you can use [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/tree/main/spring-pulsar-sample-apps/sample-pulsar-binder) and the [tests](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-pulsar/blob/main/spring-pulsar-spring-cloud-stream-binder/src/test/java/org/springframework/pulsar/spring/cloud/stream/binder/PulsarBinderIntegrationTests.java).

Comment: `maven(url = "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot")` add this to your repositories and `implementation("org.springframework.pulsar:spring-pulsar-spring-cloud-stream-binder:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT")` as dependency. This will download the dependency from SNAPSHOT **spring.io** repo.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Stream Binder for Apache Pulsar is now released and it is part of Spring Cloud Stream. Feel free to check out the following link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/pulsar/pulsar_binder.html